# Unix learning - ping command / calculate min max avg ping time

Tags: ping

I am getting used to the network topic.
If I want to extract to stdout for the amount of successful attempt while doing the ping command.
Is there any option to do it ?

for example,

ping command report the avg ping time, min ping time, max ping time, total successful attempts to the stdout:

output :
[www.cbc.ca](http://www.cbc.ca) avg=1ms max=2ms min=0.5ms success=5

How do we calculate mean/max/avg ping time in this case ?
How do we count the attempts let's say if we try to do for 10 times and use echo or awk to display the output?
Any idea ?

Appreciate the help!!!

Comment: My ping outputs the number of attempts: `10 packets transmitted, 10 received` when running `ping -c10 1.1.1.1`.

Comment: Also, there is no need to calculate the min, max and average times, since ping writes them out (mean is the same as average). Therefore, it's not quite clear to me what your question is.

Comment: I want the output to produce out the following variable : min max average

Comment: Yes. It does. Look at your question: "output : www.cbc.ca avg=1ms max=2ms min=0.5ms success=5". There is the average, there is the max, there is the min.